# gathering the iris data set. in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I want to modify the iris data set in R. It has 5 variables: species, sepal.length, sepal.width, petal.length and petal.width. I need a new column called part which specifies if it's the sepal or the petal and length and width columns which show the measurements. the result should look like this:

[image]

I also need make another one where there is a column called measure which indicates the type of measurement (length or width) and shows with the species as variables. It should look like this:

[image]

How do I do this using tidyr?

Comment: You're probably  looking for the `dplyr` function `mutate`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ahmad. What solutions have you tried thus far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach where we make a narrow format tidy data set to start, and then use `pivot_wider()` to get the result with `Length` and `Width` columns.

```
library(tidyr)
# add an ID variable so we can pivot_wider and match measurement for correct observations
id <- 1:nrow(iris)
data <- cbind(id,iris)
data %>%  gather(.,key = "part.measurement",value = "value",-id,-Species) %>%
     separate(.,part.measurement,c("part","measurement")) -> narrow_data
 head(narrow_data[2:5])

> head(narrow_data[2:5])
  Species  part measurement value
1  setosa Sepal      Length   5.1
2  setosa Sepal      Length   4.9
3  setosa Sepal      Length   4.7
4  setosa Sepal      Length   4.6
5  setosa Sepal      Length   5.0
6  setosa Sepal      Length   5.4
```

At this point we can use `pivot_wider()` to create the `Length` and `Width` columns. We'll add an `arrange()` so the sort order matches the image posted with the question.

```
narrow_data %>% pivot_wider(.,names_from = measurement,values_from = value) %>%
     arrange(Species,part)-> wide_data
head(wide_data[2:5])
```

...and the output:

```
> head(wide_data[2:5])
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Species part  Length Width
  <fct>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa  Petal    1.4   0.2
2 setosa  Petal    1.4   0.2
3 setosa  Petal    1.3   0.2
4 setosa  Petal    1.5   0.2
5 setosa  Petal    1.4   0.2
6 setosa  Petal    1.7   0.4
>
```

The second output is tricky because it essentially merges the 200 observations of part and measurement for each species of flower into an output tibble of 200 rows, one for each combination of `part` and `length` for each of the 50 observations of each `Species`.

```
#  reproduce 2nd output
speciesId <- c(1:200,1:200,1:200) # unique obs within species
narrow_species_data <- cbind(speciesId,narrow_data[order(narrow_data[,1],narrow_data[,3],narrow_data[,4]),c(2:5)])

narrow_species_data %>% pivot_wider(.,names_from= Species,values_from = value) %>%
     arrange(part,measurement,speciesId) -> wide_data_species
head(wide_data_species[2:6])
```

...and the output:

```
>  head(wide_data_species[2:6])
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  part  measurement setosa versicolor virginica
  <chr> <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Petal Length         1.4        4.7       6  
2 Petal Length         1.4        4.5       5.1
3 Petal Length         1.3        4.9       5.9
4 Petal Length         1.5        4         5.6
5 Petal Length         1.4        4.6       5.8
6 Petal Length         1.7        4.5       6.6
>
```

### A "completely tidyverse" version

Here is a version of both parts of the question that solely uses features from the `tidyverse` family of packages.

For the first question, we use `mutate()` and `seq_along()` to create unique sequential numbers to identify each observation in the original data. We create a narrow form tidy data set with `gather()`, and then convert it into the desired output with `pivot_wider()`. To match the order of observations from the image in the original question, we `arrange(Species,part)`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
# add an ID variable so we can pivot_wider and match measurement for correct observations
iris %>% mutate(id = seq_along(Species)) %>%  gather(.,key = "part.measurement",value = "value",-id,-Species) %>%
     separate(.,part.measurement,c("part","measurement")) -> narrow_data

narrow_data %>% pivot_wider(.,names_from = measurement,values_from = value) %>% 
     arrange(Species,part) -> wide_data
head(wide_data[2:5])
```

...and the output:

```
> head(wide_data[2:5])
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id part  Length Width
  <int> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 Petal    1.4   0.2
2     2 Petal    1.4   0.2
3     3 Petal    1.3   0.2
4     4 Petal    1.5   0.2
5     5 Petal    1.4   0.2
6     6 Petal    1.7   0.4
>
```

For the second question, instead of building a vector of sequential IDs for each species and using `cbind()` it to the rest of the data, we can use `dplyr` functions to create the sequences within a pipeline.

We use `arrange()` to sort the data by Species, id, part, and measurement. Then we `group_by(Species)` so we can use `mutate()` to create a unique sequential ID with `seq_along()`. The sort order is important because we want to merge the 1st observation with the 51st observation and the 101st observation.

Then we `ungroup()` to clear the `group_by()` and use `pivot_wider()` with `id_cols = speciesId` to create the desired output.

```
narrow_data %>% arrange(Species,id,part,measurement) %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(speciesId = seq_along(Species)) %>%
   ungroup(.) %>% pivot_wider(.,id_cols=c("speciesId","part","measurement"),names_from= Species,values_from = value) %>%
     arrange(part,measurement,speciesId) -> wide_data_species
head(wide_data_species[2:6])
```

...and the output:

```
> head(wide_data_species[2:6])
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  part  measurement setosa versicolor virginica
  <chr> <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Petal Length         1.4        4.7       6  
2 Petal Length         1.4        4.5       5.1
3 Petal Length         1.3        4.9       5.9
4 Petal Length         1.5        4         5.6
5 Petal Length         1.4        4.6       5.8
6 Petal Length         1.7        4.5       6.6
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer . I understood both ways of achieving the first output but couldn't really follow what was going on in the solution to the second output. This  was part of a datacamp course on ggplot2 in which they had already modified the dataset to produce the output. Any recommendations on where i can learn more about the methods you used.

Comment: @AhmadNomanAlnoor - The tidyverse is covered extensively in [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html), by Garrett Grolemund and Hadley Wickham. That said, there is quite a debate over whether one is better off learning the tidyverse or base R. The skeptic's view is represented by the essay [Tidyverse Skeptic](https://github.com/matloff/TidyverseSkeptic) by Norman Matloff.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done solely with `tidyr` functions:

First step:

```
(first <- iris %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Species, names_sep = "\\.", names_to = c("Part", ".value")))

# A tibble: 300 x 4
   Species Part  Length Width
   <fct>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 setosa  Sepal    5.1   3.5
 2 setosa  Petal    1.4   0.2
 3 setosa  Sepal    4.9   3  
 4 setosa  Petal    1.4   0.2
 5 setosa  Sepal    4.7   3.2
 6 setosa  Petal    1.3   0.2
 7 setosa  Sepal    4.6   3.1
 8 setosa  Petal    1.5   0.2
 9 setosa  Sepal    5     3.6
10 setosa  Petal    1.4   0.2
# ... with 290 more rows
```

Second step:

```
first %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = c(Length, Width), names_to = "Measure") %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Species, values_from = value, values_fn = list(value = list)) %>%
   unnest(cols = -c(Part, Measure))

# A tibble: 200 x 5
   Part  Measure setosa versicolor virginica
   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 Sepal Length     5.1        7         6.3
 2 Sepal Length     4.9        6.4       5.8
 3 Sepal Length     4.7        6.9       7.1
 4 Sepal Length     4.6        5.5       6.3
 5 Sepal Length     5          6.5       6.5
 6 Sepal Length     5.4        5.7       7.6
 7 Sepal Length     4.6        6.3       4.9
 8 Sepal Length     5          4.9       7.3
 9 Sepal Length     4.4        6.6       6.7
10 Sepal Length     4.9        5.2       7.2
# ... with 190 more rows
```

Comment: The output from your solution does not exactly match the output from the question. One needs to account for the sequencing of observations in the iris data set in order to exactly match the images posted with the original question.

Comment: @LenGreski - There's nothing in OPs question that indicates that the order is important.  You've taken the image literally, I haven't.  Trivial to implement, but will leave to OP to clarify.

Comment: Point taken. What's interesting about the images is that in order to reproduce them one must account for the ordering of the observations in the original data set.  The fact that the earliest version of my answer didn't exactly match the images bothered me, so I kept updating my solution until I could reproduce the content from the images. I'll also note that the second part of the problem is ridiculous -- matching the 1st, 51st, and 101st observations is useless for actually analyzing the iris data.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I can suggest to achieve the first result:

```
df <- iris

# Changing column order
df <- df %>%
  select(5, 1:4)
```

Selecting Species, Petal.Length, Sepal.Length columns and gathering:

```
length <- df %>% 
  select(1,2,4) %>%
  gather("Part", "Length", -1)

length$Part <- gsub(pattern = ".Length", replacement = "", length$Part, )

head(length)
  Species  Part Length
1  setosa Sepal    5.1
2  setosa Sepal    4.9
3  setosa Sepal    4.7
4  setosa Sepal    4.6
5  setosa Sepal    5.0
6  setosa Sepal    5.4
```

Selecting Species, Petal.Width, Sepal.Width columns and gathering:

```
width <- df %>% 
  select(1,3,5) %>%
  gather("Part", "Width", -1)

width$Part <- gsub(pattern = ".Width", replacement = "", width$Part, )

head(width)
  Species  Part Width
1  setosa Sepal   3.5
2  setosa Sepal   3.0
3  setosa Sepal   3.2
4  setosa Sepal   3.1
5  setosa Sepal   3.6
6  setosa Sepal   3.9
```

Combinig the 2 datasets:

```
merged_df <- length %>%
  mutate(Width = width$Width)

head(merged_df)
  Species  Part Length Width
1  setosa Sepal    5.1   3.5
2  setosa Sepal    4.9   3.0
3  setosa Sepal    4.7   3.2
4  setosa Sepal    4.6   3.1
5  setosa Sepal    5.0   3.6
6  setosa Sepal    5.4   3.9
```

Comment: The output from your solution does not exactly match the images posted in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
# Pivotting iris to long data
long_iris <- iris |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = !c(id, Species), 
    names_to = c("Part", "Measure"),
    names_sep = "\\." # Iris variable separator regex
  )
long_iris
#> # A tibble: 600 x 5
#>    Species    id Part  Measure value
#>    <fct>   <int> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 setosa      1 Sepal Length    5.1
#>  2 setosa      1 Sepal Width     3.5
#>  3 setosa      1 Petal Length    1.4
#>  4 setosa      1 Petal Width     0.2
#>  5 setosa      2 Sepal Length    4.9
#>  6 setosa      2 Sepal Width     3  
#>  7 setosa      2 Petal Length    1.4
#>  8 setosa      2 Petal Width     0.2
#>  9 setosa      3 Sepal Length    4.7
#> 10 setosa      3 Sepal Width     3.2
#> # ... with 590 more rows

# Using the long data, we can repivot to a long format

iris_length_width <- long_iris |> 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(id, Species, Part),
    names_from = Measure,
    values_from = value
  )
# This achieves the same thing
iris |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = !c(id, Species), 
    names_to = c("Part", ".value"),
    names_sep = "\\." # Iris variable separator regex
  )
#> # A tibble: 300 x 5
#>    Species    id Part  Length Width
#>    <fct>   <int> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 setosa      1 Sepal    5.1   3.5
#>  2 setosa      1 Petal    1.4   0.2
#>  3 setosa      2 Sepal    4.9   3  
#>  4 setosa      2 Petal    1.4   0.2
#>  5 setosa      3 Sepal    4.7   3.2
#>  6 setosa      3 Petal    1.3   0.2
#>  7 setosa      4 Sepal    4.6   3.1
#>  8 setosa      4 Petal    1.5   0.2
#>  9 setosa      5 Sepal    5     3.6
#> 10 setosa      5 Petal    1.4   0.2
#> # ... with 290 more rows
```

2nd part

```r
long_iris
#> # A tibble: 600 x 5
#>    Species    id Part  Measure value
#>    <fct>   <int> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 setosa      1 Sepal Length    5.1
#>  2 setosa      1 Sepal Width     3.5
#>  3 setosa      1 Petal Length    1.4
#>  4 setosa      1 Petal Width     0.2
#>  5 setosa      2 Sepal Length    4.9
#>  6 setosa      2 Sepal Width     3  
#>  7 setosa      2 Petal Length    1.4
#>  8 setosa      2 Petal Width     0.2
#>  9 setosa      3 Sepal Length    4.7
#> 10 setosa      3 Sepal Width     3.2
#> # ... with 590 more rows

# creating a row id by group to create the second output
long_iris |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(id, Part, Measure),
    names_from = Species,
    values_from = value
  ) |> 
  arrange(Measure, Part) |> 
  select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 200 x 5
#>    Part  Measure setosa versicolor virginica
#>    <chr> <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 Petal Length     1.4        4.7       6  
#>  2 Petal Length     1.4        4.5       5.1
#>  3 Petal Length     1.3        4.9       5.9
#>  4 Petal Length     1.5        4         5.6
#>  5 Petal Length     1.4        4.6       5.8
#>  6 Petal Length     1.7        4.5       6.6
#>  7 Petal Length     1.4        4.7       4.5
#>  8 Petal Length     1.5        3.3       6.3
#>  9 Petal Length     1.4        4.6       5.8
#> 10 Petal Length     1.5        3.9       6.1
#> # ... with 190 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>